# C++ compilation error: error: expected primary-expression before ‘try’

Tags: c++

Error:

```
/home/mike/Documents/PROJECTS/BUN/blib/bun/impl/DbBackend.hpp:61:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘try’
                     try {
                     ^~~
/home/mike/Documents/PROJECTS/BUN/blib/bun/impl/DbBackend.hpp:67:21: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘catch’
                     catch (std::exception const &except) {
                     ^~~~~
In file included from blib/bun/bun.hpp:3:0,
                 from main.cpp:12:
```

Part of code:

```
                bool connect(std::string const &in_params) {
                    const auto backend_factory =
#ifdef BUN_SQLITE
                    soci::sqlite3;
#elif defined(BUN_POSTGRES)
                    soci::postgresql;
#elif defined(BUN_MYSQL)
                    soci::mysql;
#endif
                    try {
                         if (!_ok) {
                                          _sql_session.open(backend_factory, in_params);
                                          _ok = true;
                                   }
                    }
                    catch (std::exception const &except) {
                                     l().error(except.what());
                        _ok = false;
                    }
                              return _ok;
                }

                soci::session &session() {
                    return _sql_session;
                }
            };
```

Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib   \
-I/home/mike/Documents/PROJECTS/BUN/third_party/unqlite -I/home/mike/Documents/PROJECTS/BUN -I/home/mike/Documents/PROJECTS/BUN/third_party
# LDLIBS :=  -lpthread -lresolv
EXECUTABLE := main
# CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++17 -Wall

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) *.o
```

I am trying to use Bun orm. In my program I only included bun.hpp file. I can't understand what is not ok for compiler before try ? Maybe because of that `#ifdef` operators above the try ? Also it says it expected `,` or `;` before catch...

I am trying on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is C++ code.

Comment: And please sort out the formatting to make it readable

Comment: Are your defines properly... defined (BUN_SQLITE etc)? Seems like some ill-defined MACRO problem

Comment: Could you make this problem *reproducable*, perhaps? Self-contained? You'll probably *find* the problem on the route, but even if not, it would make a much better question...

Comment: Usually variables with underscore infront of them are private

Comment: I expect that non of your macros are defined and as this the result will be something like `const auto backend_factory = try {`

Comment: If none of the three `BUN_xxx` macros is defined, then there's a hanging statment; maybe add an `#else` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compile line doesn't define any of the options (unless they are coming from inside the file or another header) so you get:

```
bool connect(std::string const &in_params) {
                const auto backend_factory =
                try {
```

To confirm you can add a "-E" to the g++ line to get the source after the preprocessor.

Another possibility is that you are defining more than one.
You could always `#undef` 2 of them and `#define` the last one to see if it compiles that way (just as a test).

Comment: This is worth TWO upvotes from me.  One is for anticipating the preprocessed source code you posted, and two is for offering that option for people to use in this situation.

Comment: @donjuedo This isn't the first weird compiler error I've met :-) I'm currently porting some ancient Solaris C++ that uses a mix of generated makefiles (from Imake), hand rolled makefiles and shell scripts to build. The only way to figure some bits out is write a script called `CC` that is before the real `CC` on the path and inject a `-E` to see what is actually going on!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all #def macros and leave only one and check if it compiles, for example const `auto backend_factory = soci::sqlite3;` If it does compile that means you're not defining one of those 3 def you have in your code